# How do I center a <td> when the button is altering the padding in the same <tr>?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

I'm creating an HTML table with JSP and the styles are using Bootstrap.  I have two columns, one with a button and the other with text.

They're both intended to have the same padding in the table, `12px` top and bottom.  The button column does have that padding on both the top and the bottom, but the text part does not.

I think what's happening is that the second column's top padding gets set up the way it's intended, and then the rest of the padding just sort of fills in.  I have two images and the code below.

The first image shows the padding around the button, and the second image shows the padding around the text.

[image: Button padding is correct]
[image: Text padding is off]

```
<tbody>
    <c:forEach items="${results.items}" var="result">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form action method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                    <div hidden>
                        <input name="itemUri" value="${result.uri}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="buttons">
                        <input class="btn btn-info"  type="submit" value="See">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span class="align-middle v-100">Green Eggs and Ham</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

This won't change the padding, but the padding is ok for the button so you can hopefully just adjust the centering of the text.

Bootstrap add `vertical-align: top` to `td`s. You can adjust with

```
vertical-align: inherit
or
vertical-align: middle
```

The text still might not appear vertically centered, but it is aligned with the button's text. i think it then becomes of question of the button's padding and/or line-height.

Comment: I also removed `align-middle` from the span which helped a tiny bit. https://jsfiddle.net/wazz/ffr9210a/